# Java 8 stream's toArray and size parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I was wondering how stream().toArray[x -> new Integer[x]] knows what size of array to from? I wrote a snippet in which i created a list of an integer of size 4 and filtered the values and it created an array of length of the filtered stream, I could not see any method on stream to get a size of the stream.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);
intList.add(3);
intList.add(4);


    Integer[] array = intList.stream()
                             .filter(x -> x > 2)
                             .toArray(x -> {
                                System.out.println("x --> " + x);
                                return new Integer[x];
                              });

System.out.println("array length: " + array.length);
```

Output of above code:

```
x --> 2
array length: 2
```

initially, the snippet was like

```
Integer[] array = intList.stream()
                 .filter(x -> x > 2)
                 .toArray(x -> new Integer[x]);
```

Just to get the understanding what value of x it passes i had  to change it to  print x in lambda

Comment: `toArray` is a [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). When you get to `toArray`, it evaluates the whole stream, and at that point knows how many items it has.

Comment: I know toArray was a terminal operation but i was interested in how it knows the size of stream?? I was thinking Stream Api would have a method called size() which i couldn't find?

Comment: @Loks It's called `count()`

Comment: Instead of `x -> new Integer[x]` you can write `Integer[]::new` ;)

Comment: so you say toArray calls count()?? I am interested in how the value of X is found? Answer my question you get 100 points :)

Comment: I know i could use method reference but i was breaking and playing with lambda to understand how the size is found.

Comment: For the record : you might want to consider accepting the most helpful answer at some point.

Comment: @Loks I'll second GhostCat - why not accept the answer from Holger?

Answer (score 7):

Of course, this is implementation dependent. For some streams, the size is predicable, if the source has a known size and no size changing intermediate operation is involved. Since you are using a `filter` operation, this doesn’t apply, however, there is an estimate size, based on the unfiltered count.

Now, the Stream implementation simply allocates a temporary buffer, either using the estimated size or a default size with support for increasing the capacity, if necessary, and copies the data into the destination array, created by your function, in a final step.

The intermediate buffers could be created via the supplied function, which is the reason why [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) states “…*using the provided generator function to allocate the returned array, as well as any additional arrays that might be required for a partitioned execution or for resizing*” and I vaguely remember seeing such a behavior in early versions. However, the current implementation just uses `Object[]` arrays (or `Object[][]` in a [“spined buffer”](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/SpinedBuffer.java)) for intermediate storage and uses the supplied function only for creating the final array. Therefore, you can’t observe intermediate array creation with the function, given this specific JRE implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is: this is a *[terminal](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/stream-terminal-operations-example/)* operation. It happens in the end, when the stream was processed: meaning - the "final" count is known by then; as there are no more operations that could remove/add values to the stream!

Comment: I was thinking how it knows the final count? Is it the way functional programmer think rather not worrying about how it is done?

Comment: @Loks it creates a collection which contains all the references, then it knows the length and calls this lambda.

Answer (score 4):

Simply look at javas stream documentation of toArray.

---

```
<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)
```

Returns an array containing the elements of this stream, using the provided generator function to allocate the returned array, as well as any additional arrays that might be required for a partitioned execution or for resizing.

This is a terminal operation.

API Note:
    **The generator function takes an integer, which is the size of the desired array, and produces an array of the desired size.** This can be concisely expressed with an array constructor reference

---

Therefore `toArray` does give you the desired array size as a parameter and you are responsible for allocating a correct sized array, at least when using this method. This method is a terminal operation. So the size calculation is done within the internals of the Stream API.

IMHO it is better to grasp if you name your lambda parameters differently for filter and toArray.

```
Integer[] array = intList.stream()
                 .filter(myint -> myint > 2)
                 .toArray(desiredArraySize -> new Integer[desiredArraySize]);
```

Comment: You can also write .toArray(Integer[]::new).

Comment: But then you don't use the size parameter, do you.

Comment: Actually I do.  `Integer[]::new` is unary function taking an int as parameter.

Comment: Cool. Thx for clarifying that.

Comment: @ Florian F then what is the value of the int parameter in Integer[]::new

Comment: Look at the toArray method, it takes a lambda that receives the needed size.